# Group and sum data from a 2d array then map totals to another 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum, mapping, grouping

I need to sum a column of values in one array grouped by another column and map those results to another array based on a specific column value.

Sample Input:

```
$milestones = [
    [
        'id' => '1578453e53090b',
        'milestone' => 'Wireframe',
        'assigned_to' => 9
    ],
    [
        'id' => '1578453e530975',
        'milestone' => 'Development'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '1578453e530943',
        'milestone' => 'Design',
        'assigned_to' => 2
    ]
];

$tasks = [
    [
        'id' => '15786dc59333f2',
        'status' => 'Open',
        'progress' => 5,
        'milestone' => '1578453e53090b'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '15786dc669d451',
        'status' => 'Open',
        'progress' => 10,
        'milestone' => '1578453e53090b'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '15786dc7ccbea3',
        'status' => 'Open',
        'progress' => 20,
        'milestone' => '1578453e530943'
    ]
];
```

I need to get the sum of the `progress` values in the `$tasks` array grouped by `milestone` then store/append those totals to the `$milestones` array.

Desired Output:

```
[
    [
        'id' => '1578453e53090b',
        'milestone' => 'Wireframe',
        'assigned_to' => 9,
        'total' => 15
    ],
    [
        'id' => '1578453e530975',
        'milestone' => 'Development'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '1578453e530943',
        'milestone' => 'Design',
        'assigned_to' => 2,
        'total' => 20
    ]
]
```

Comment: you could iterate over each array and build a third multidimensional array using your ID as the index, that will make linking the two value sources easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is to just use `foreach`. Use the first `foreach` for the `milestones` getting the ID that will match the second `foreach` for `tasks` in `milestone`.

After that, use a simple `$total` container to be used continually andatch them using a simple `if`.

```
foreach($milestones as &$m) {
                //     ^ add reference to make changes
    $total = 0; // initialize total holder
    foreach($tasks as $task) {
        if($task['milestone'] === $m['id']) { // if it matches
            $total += $task['progress']; // add
        }
    }

    $m['total'] = $total; // after its done, add another key pair being total and its value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array mapping should do the trick:

```
//will add 'progress' key to each milestone
$tabulate_progress = function($milestone) use ($tasks) {
    $milestone['progress'] = 0; //start with 0 progress

    foreach($tasks as $task):
        //add to progress if we find a matching task
        if($task['milestone']===$milestone['id'])
            $milestone['progress']+=$task['progress'];
    endforeach;

    return $milestone;
};
$milestones = array_map($tabulate_progress,$milestones);
```

[Here's a demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6b340d86e90ce139898a43b82e1eb7f552e64c2).

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested loop approach is unnecessarily expensive -- it is simply doing too many unnecessary cycles while checking for matches in the inner loop.

Instead, perform one loop over the `$milestones` array and declare a unique reference to each row. Then perform one loop over the `$tasks` array to add each new encounter's `progress` value to its mapped/referenced row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CGSR4))

```
foreach ($milestones as &$row) {
    $ref[$row['id']] = &$row;
}

foreach ($tasks as ['milestone' => $m, 'progress' => $p]) {
    $ref[$m]['total'] = ($ref[$m]['total'] ?? 0) + $p;
}
var_export($milestones);
```

<sub>This approach is assumed to be safe because ALL task rows have a `milestone` value which correlates to milestone row `id`s and ALL `id` values in the milestones array are unique.</sub>